# How to reset ReCaptcha box on successful form submission

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have a form on my website that uses ReCaptcha2. After the form is successfully completed and you get the success message, the form fields (name, email, message) are cleared but the ReCaptcha box remains ticked. Is there any way to clear this box after successful submission of the form or is there a way to permanently show the success message (as opposed to it fading out after a few seconds) and remove the entire form from the page. Ideally the success message would remain on the page until it is refreshed. I still want the existing other error messages to fade in and out as they currently do.

At present the initial Captcha error message reads "You did not check the box, a bot was detected or you have already sent this form. Please check the box or refresh this page & try again". The refresh suggestion is to cover the instance where the user presses send again and ReCaptcha has been left ticked from a previous successful submission (ie they try to send the form twice). Hence why I would like to implement one of the solutions posed in my question. Thanks in advance for any help given. Here is working URL of the form (at the bottom of the page)

http://www.topolinowebdesigns.uk/test-site/aerocoat/index-v2.html

```
<?php

    /*
    +-----------------------------------------------------+
    | GOOGLE reCAPTCHA YOUR PUBLIC AND PRIVATE KEY        |
    | You can collect public and secret key from here:    |
    | https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin              |
    +-----------------------------------------------------+
    */
    $recaptcha_secretkey = "My secret key";

    // GOOGLE reCAPTCHA Validation Check
    ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);


    $message = "";
    $status = "false";

    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        $userIP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $recaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $secretKey = $recaptcha_secretkey;
        $request = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secretKey}&response={$recaptchaResponse}&remoteip={$userIP}");

        if( !strstr( $request, "true" ) ) {
            $message = '<p align="justify"><strong>Captcha Error!</strong> You did not check the box, a bot was detected or you have already sent this form. Please check the box or refresh this page & try again.</p>';
            $status = "false";


        } else {
            require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
            require_once('phpmailer/class.smtp.php');

            $mail = new PHPMailer();


            //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3; // Enable verbose debug output
            /*$mail->isSMTP();                // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'my hostname';      // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;           // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'my username';  // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'my password';  // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';        // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 465;                // TCP port to connect to*/


            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
                if( $_POST['form_name'] != '' AND $_POST['form_email'] != '' ) {

                    $name = $_POST['form_name'];
                    $email = $_POST['form_email'];
                    $message = $_POST['form_message'];

                    $subject = 'New Message | Contact Form';

                    $botcheck = $_POST['form_botcheck'];

                    $toemail = 'my email address'; // Your Email Address
                    $toname = 'my name'; // Your Name

                    if( $botcheck == '' ) {

                        $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
                        $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
                        $mail->AddAddress( $toemail , $toname );
                        $mail->Subject = $subject;

                        $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
                        $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
                        $message = isset($message) ? "Message: $message<br><br>" : '';

                        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

                        $body = "$name $email $message $referrer";

                        $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
                        $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

                        if( $sendEmail == true ):
                            $message = '<p align="justify"><strong>Success!</strong> We have received your message and will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>';
                            $status = "true";
                        else:
                            $message = '<p align="justify"><strong>Attention!</strong> Your message could not be sent due to an unexpected error. Please try again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '</p>';
                            $status = "false";
                        endif;
                    } else {
                        $message = '<p align="justify"><strong>Bot Detected!</strong> Your efforts are futile!</p>';
                        $status = "false";
                    }
                } else {
                    $message = '<p align="justify"><strong>Warning!</strong> Please complete all the fields and try again.</p>';
                    $status = "false";
                }
            } else {
                $message = '<p align="justify"><strong>Unexpected Error!</strong> Please try again later.</p>';
                $status = "false";
            }
        }
        $status_array = array( 'message' => $message, 'status' => $status);
        echo json_encode($status_array);
    }
    ?>
```

In addition here is the validation script that runs on the html page just after the form ends.

```
<script>
                           $("#contact_form").validate({
                             submitHandler: function(form) {
                               var form_btn = $(form).find('button[type="submit"]');
                               var form_result_div = '#form-result';
                               $(form_result_div).remove();
                               form_btn.before('<div id="form-result" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: none;"></div>');
                               var form_btn_old_msg = form_btn.html();
                               form_btn.html(form_btn.prop('disabled', true).data("loading-text"));
                               $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                                 dataType:  'json',
                                 success: function(data) {
                                   if( data.status === 'true' ) {
                                     $(form).find('.form-control').val('');
                                   }
                                   form_btn.prop('disabled', false).html(form_btn_old_msg);
                                   $(form_result_div).html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
                                   setTimeout(function(){ $(form_result_div).fadeOut('slow') }, 8000);
                                 }
                               });
                             }
                           });
                        </script>
```